# Delphi Audio record sample Not working on ios 12.0.1 and ios 12.1

Tags: delphi

This [Sample Code from Delphi](https://sourceforge.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/HEAD/tarball?path=/branches/RADStudio_Tokyo/Object%20Pascal/Mobile%20Snippets/AudioRecPlay) doesnt work on IOS 12.0.1 and IOS 12.1
I get message

> Project AudioRecPlay raised exception class 6

but works perfect on all other 32 bit versions of IOS any idea why this happen or how can i catch the error?

Comment: You probably need to add the NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key to the Version Info section of the Project Options for iOS Device 32 bit (as per the one for iOS Device 64 bit)

Comment: Can you post It as Answer please? I spend 3 days Trying to fix the error and you save my next month searching!!!!!!!!!!!! post it as answer so i can give you the credits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key to the Version Info section of the Project Options for iOS Device 32 bit (as per the one for iOS Device 64 bit).

To add the key, right-click on the grid with Keys and Values, and click Add Key. Enter NSMicrophoneUsageDescription for the key and click OK. You can then enter a Value for the Key.

Similar to the procedure laid out here:

https://www.delphiworlds.com/2016/09/handling-new-ios-10-privacy-settings/

Comment: You save my month!